# Connecting corners to form rectangles in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, connected-components, corner-detection

I'm trying to detect CText fields on rasterized PDFs by converting them to PNG format then analyzing the images with OpenCV.

So far I've been able to produce a set of corners that are relatively accurate with the following code:

```
image = cv2.imread(img_filename)
# add 10px border padding (white)
image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[255, 255, 255])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
corners = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.1)

cond = corners>0.0001*corners.max()
image[cond] = [0,0,255]
cv2.imshow('dst', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here's my input:
[image: https://gyazo.com/88123222a2fdc9afc9b8bc038a1bda3e]

And here's the output:
[image: https://gyazo.com/205b857ded03669f625d664965566b30]

I want to be able to compute from this set of points, which points are part of a rectangle. This would involve checking that for each corner point, three other corner points exist:

1. A point in the same row (approximately), but different column
2. A point in the same column (approximately), but different row
3. A point with the column from (1) above and the row from (2) above

The goal is to produce a set of rectangles that *do not* contain any [significant] amount of corner points inside of them, unless those corner points belong to a rectangle themselves (in the case of the bounding rectangle of each inner rectangle, for ex.)

What is the most efficient way to do this in OpenCV?

Comment: I'd assume that you'll get into some trouble distinguishing these corners from corners in letters. Why don't you use edge detection and/or  HoughLines and single out lines with a minimum length and certain direction (horizontal, verical)?

Comment: Furthermore, gray value information may be important, you could suppress back lines to get rid of the letters and keep the lines of the boxes only.

Comment: I need this to be more or less universal. I plan to train the weights eventually, but corner detection has proven far more accurate for the majority of cases.

Comment: As for the text, assume that it is not an issue. I'll be detecting readable characters and masking them before this operation.

Comment: So if you can detect letters successfully, why don't you treat each box as a symbol and train for it?

Comment: Fair point. I just thought this operation was mathematically straightforward enough to not require training. It's just a matter of optimizing the search. I'm not familiar enough with OpenCV to know if a solution already exists.

Comment: You'll probably have to define "more or less universal" in more detail. Will the sizes of the boxes change? Their colour? Their orientation be other than horizontal and vertical? This may influence a lot what type of algorithm you want to select.

Comment: Sure, sorry. The color of the boxes can change. Their orientation will only be horizontal. The defining factor is a set of rectangles next to one another of similar areas. For now though, all I need to do is connect those Harris corners in a way that minimizes the number of lonely corners within each rectangle :P